Can you sum the SHAP values of multiple lagged variables?
I want to assess feature importance of a gradient boosting machine model made to forecast the count outcome $Y$. The data is a time series and I'm introducing lagged forms of the predictors in the model, e.g.: $X$, $X_{t-1}$, $X_{t-2}$,$X_{t-3}$ are all part of the model features, where $X$ is a given predictor and $t$ the time lagged at three moments. My question is, when I'm assessing feature importance through average marginal SHapley Additive exPlanations (SHAP) (so averaged over each feature), can I sum $X$ and all the $X$ lagged features into one and unique SHAP value?

I mostly understand this question and have upvoted. However, what is your question? You most certainly can add up real numbers and get an outcome. Do you mean something like if that sum will jointly describe the importance of all of the lags (e.g., "The first four lags are important, though we aren't pinning down which one in particular might be most important.")?

Yes mostly, will that sum describe the overall importance of the feature, "independently" of the lag? Adding X SHAP value and all of its lagged version SHAP values. e.g.: X is the most important feature to predict Y.

Basically this post from Stackoverflow answers my question:
"The short answer is yes, you can add up SHAP values across the columns to get the importance of a whole group of features (just make sure you don't take the absolute value like we do when going across rows for global feature importance).
The long answer is that when Shapley values "fairly" allocate credit for interaction effects between features, they assume each feature in an interaction effect should get equal credit for the interaction. This means that for high order interaction terms you might get slightly different results when running Shapley values before (and summing) vs. after grouping features (since the new group just gets one chunk of the interaction pie so to speak, as opposed to multiple chunks when it was several features). These differences are typically small though so I wouldn't sweat it much since both ways are reasonable."

It's great that you posted a solution after answering your own question. You can also accept your own answer!
